# Catch Block not getting called from the inner loop in BizTalk orchestration

Tags: loops, exception, try-catch, biztalk-2013, orchestration

In my BizTalk orchestration, I have 2 loops, one inner and one outer. When an exception occurs in the outer loop, the control goes to the catch exception block (which catches System.Exception), but if any exception happens in the inner loop, the catch block does not get called. All my processing takes place inside the inner loop, but I am unable to catch any Exception.

The BizTalk console event viewer though captured the exception from the inner loop, (Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException) but the catch block did not get called.

Can anyone help on how to handle the exception from inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

If is suspending with a Unhandled Exception then you are probably trying to catch it with a  `System.SystemException` an not a `System.Exception`, as `System.SystemException` won't catch `XLang` exceptions.  Make sure you are using `System.SystemException`,

You can also add another catch block to the scope and make that one catch General Exception, which should cover everything.

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf, I am using System.Exception only in the outer scope , but still the XLANg exception from the inner loop is not being caught. I am not using System.SystemException. Please suggest. Just for test I intentionally created an exception in the outer loop code and the catch block was called, but when exception happens in the inner loop, even System.Exception catch block does not get called. Please suggest.

Comment: @PoonamChandak There must be something else going on, as just having two loops would not cause that.  Do you also have a scope around the inner loop?  If so, does it have a catch block?

Comment: HI.. @Dijkgraaf.. I am now having just one loop. and only 1 scope at the start and one catch handler catching System.Exception object, but still the orchestration flow does not go to the catch block at all. Can you elaborate? do i need to reinstall the DLLs in GAC? or something else might be the issue. I had installed the dlls earlier by admin console.Please suggest.

Comment: @PoonamChandak You should not be manually installing the DLL in the GAC.   You should be deploying from Visual Studio in Dev and MSI packages in all other environments.   Yes, try re-deploying your whole solution.